# How much resistance is required to go from 240 volts to 24 volts (AC) or less?

Tags: voltage, resistance, step-down

I live in the UK with a mains supply at 220 to 240 VAC. I'm trying to connect a Ring Video Doorbell which requires only 8 to 24 VAC so I need something to step-down the voltage with a minimal footprint if possible.

How much resistance is required to go from 240 volts to 24 volts (AC) or less?

In other words, do I need a bunch of resistors on a circuit board, do they need to be in parallel or serial, or will just one do that has the correct ohm resistance?

Comment: What do you want this for?power somedevice? get a proper PSU

Comment: It is likely that resistors are *not* the best solution. What *exactly* are you trying to do? In other words, what device are you trying to connect to a 24VAC supply? How much current does it use? Basically, please explain the *underlying* problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The correct way is to use a transformer. Using just resistors is nearly always a bad idea

Comment: We're going to need some context. If you're driving some high-impedance input then you can get away with high-value resistors in a voltage divider. If you want to operate a device that requires 24VAC as power you're better off with a transformer rather than a stray heating element as your means of wasting energy.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish here?  Measure the line voltage?  Power something?  Produce lots of smoke and sparks?

Comment: I'll edit the question...

Comment: Because we have no idea regarding the input impedance of your doorbell we can't accurately suggest a resistor-based approach (not that it would be a good idea in terms of cost, heating, footprint, and fire risk). Use a transformer.

Comment: You can add electrocution risk to the ones listed by @hexafraction.  If the doorbell is only designed for up to 24V, then it's unlikely to be insulated to 240V standards.  But without an isolating transformer, it could become live, especially if the neutral were disconnected.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **electrical home improvement** questions have been determined to best fit on **http://diy.stackexchange.com/** rather than here.

Answer (score 4):

Resistors are the wrong tool for the job here.  What you need to get is a 240V to 24V transformer.

It looks like the 8-24 VAC spec is set up so that you can power it with a standard doorbell transformer, which may already be installed in your house.  If not, I imagine you should be able to pick one up at a hardware store.

It's likely that the first thing the video doorbell circuit does internally is rectify the AC into DC.  If you can make that determination, then it may be possible to power the unit off of 8-24 VDC, if procuring a DC power supply is easier.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying to find a suitable transformer but it's proving elusive. Thought I'd just use resistors instead, or build my own transformer. How hard can it be? :)

Comment: Well, a transformer is not built from resistors, it's two (or more) coils of wire around a magnetically permeable core.  You could build one yourself, but you would need a lot of magnet wire.  It's probably easier to find a transformer.  However, it might be worth looking at the circuit board in the video doorbell to see if it could be powered off of DC as maybe it would be easier to find a DC power supply than a transformer.

Comment: I'd rather not make any changes to the doorbell. Instead I'm looking to add something between the installed mechanical doorbell unit inside the house and the video door bell purchased. Effectively intercepting the power supply and stepping it down.

Comment: You're sure the mechanical doorbell is operating on 240 volts?  Usually that's powered by a 24V or so doorbell transformer in the house somewhere.

Comment: Google has some pictures of typical doorbell transformers: https://www.google.com/search?q=doorbell+transformer&source=lnms&tbm=isch

Comment: Yes, however the information found by Sam Gibson (unclear why that is deleted) seems to indicate that the device is intended to be placed *in series* with the ringer bell in a circuit powered by a bell transfer.  Apparently if an actual bell is not used, then not only is the bell transfer still required, but also a series resistor is required to simulate the load of the bell.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Hi - I had just written-up an answer, but now I see that the OP has disclosed a new fact i.e. that they have an exiting powered doorbell. That changes the answer, based on what I read on the Ring website, therefore I deleted what I wrote to avoid being misleading, despite having spent time on the research I did, because of this new info :-(

Comment: Interesting.  Well, my guess is the need for an extra series resistance is going to be device-dependent: consult the manual!  And the transformer is obviously still required, but one may already be present for the existing doorbell.

Comment: To ring a traditional ringer, it would have to have some internal switching device that basically shorts its two terminals.  Without a load, it would be shorting the bell transformer, which seems potentially problematic.  It's an interesting question how they power it while doing so - perhaps they use an SCR or TRIAC and delay firing it long enough to get some energy to keep a capacitor charged.  Or maybe the whole video mechanism is in parallel with an actual mechanical switch, and blanks out when the switch is pushed.

Comment: This is the reason I'm on here. I'm no expert unfortunately, however I've dabbled in electronics and was looking forward to getting my soldering iron out again. It looks like this is a bad idea and I tend to agree. Whether the door bell is already transformed down, I'm not sure? The actual door bell outside is a very basic one, press to ring bell, depress to get second ring. Press multiple times to annoy occupants.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "It's an interesting question how they power it while doing so" - FYI this video doorbell has a built-in large Li-Ion battery, lasting 6-12 months. Therefore AC power isn't *required*, but can be used to recharge the battery "*in situ*".

Comment: @SamGibson - Yes power is not the issue for me, rather I'd like to replace the existing doorbell with the new one, adding the new 'Smart Home' functionality.

Comment: My guess is that if you already have a doorbell installed, you already have a doorbell transformer installed.  It's just a matter of where.  There is no way somebody ran 240 VAC to the button next to the door.  It would be a good idea to find it and confirm.  Not sure where the standard installation location is in UK homes.  In the US, they can show up in odd places - like in a closet near the actual bell.  You may be able to just replace the button with the video doorbell without any additional parts.

Comment: @BillyRayValentine - (a) Your questions really should be directed to the manufacturer's support imho. (b) The newly disclosed fact that you have an existing powered doorbell seems (based on my research) to change the options, which made my previous research obsolete and also makes it difficult to help you, since we (and, I think, you) don't currently know enough about the existing doorbell power supply & wiring, and us readers can't see or measure it remotely! Good luck, but after spending time on previous research, I'm not able to help further.

Comment: @SamGibson - Thanks for your help. I did actually ring the support team before coming here. There advice was to use a resistor... but they weren't sure how much resistance etc. was required. I'll do some more googling and try and find the doorbell manual.

Comment: @BillyRayValentine - their advice to use the resistor was almost certainly in the assumed context of a **standard bell transformer NOT HAZARDOUS DIRECT CONNECTION TO THE AC MAINS**.

Comment: I think you should go hunting for the transformer that's probably *already installed* in your house.  If you can confirm that it's the proper voltage (it probably is) and you're not going to bypass the existing bell, then I think you should be able to just install the thing without any extra parts.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - That's fair comment, but they could have been a bit more explicit... helps people like me who occasionally (to often) act on impulse and start looking on Wikipedia thinking all I need is the right mathematical formula for resistance vs power output and a soldering iron. :)

Comment: @alex.forencich - I'm gonna research the existing bell a bit more. Having already installed it though and witnessed the bell work the first time and then seemingly short out or fail in some way until I switched the power off means I think I'm heading in the right direction. Want to be double sure though.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need 8-24V, I'd say use an adapter or a battery.

Comment: I think you have given a generic answer, which is not suitable for this *specific* device. While I was researching an answer for the OP, everything I found on the manufacturer's website said the external power supply (if used) *must* provide AC. Please explain (and give a website reference which confirms) how this specific device can use a normal (DC) adapter or a (DC) battery.

Comment: As @SamGibson says, a battery is not the issue. It already has power and the instructions mention AC power therefore I need to hook up the new doorbell by reducing the output, if possible.

Comment: i'm sure an ac to ac adapter might work then. here's a link for a 120V input, 12V output adapter. i think you'll be able to find one for 240V input as well. https://www.amazon.com/UpBright%C2%AE-New-12V-Adapter-Model/dp/B00QVLMDDY

Comment: That type of adapter is no good to me. If anything I need something a bit more like: http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/2x50v-800va-toroidal-transformer-a70qj

Comment: @BillyRayValentine - no, the device at your link is entirely mis-fit for your application.